# How to filter a data frame by column using a vector in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame (n * m). I calculate a cutoff for each column, thus I get a vector (1 * m) containing the cutoff for each column. So my question is how to filtering this data frame by column using the cutoff for each column? For example, I would like to replace the values lower than the cutoff to NA. Here is my original code which is not correct. Any suggestion is welcome. Thanks:)

```
x<-as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(100, mean = 10, sd = 2),nrow=10))
x_Q1<-apply(x, 2, quantile, 0.25, na.rm = TRUE)
x_IQR<-apply(as.matrix(x), 2, IQR, na.rm = TRUE)
x_low_outlier<-x_Q1-x_IQR
x[x<x_low_outlier]<-NA
```

Comment: Hi @RonakShah Here is my example: 
x<-as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(100, mean = 10, sd = 2),nrow=10))
x_Q1<-apply(x, 2, quantile, 0.25, na.rm = TRUE)
x_IQR<-apply(as.matrix(x), 2, IQR, na.rm = TRUE)
x_low_outlier<-x_Q1-x_IQR
x[x<x_low_outlier]<-NA. But the last code is not correct.

Comment: In this example, the expected output is replacing the values in each column lower than x_low_outlier to NA.@RonakShah Could you please help me? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can compare every column of `x` with every value in  `x_low_outlier` and replace those that are below `x_low_outlier` to `NA`.

Here are two ways of doing this.

You can double transpose.

```
x[t(t(x) < x_low_outlier)] <- NA
```

Or with `sweep` :

```
x[sweep(x, 2, x_low_outlier, `<`)] <- NA
```

Comment: Thank you so much! One more question: why did you double transpose the x? What's the difference between "x[t(t(x) < x_low_outlier)] <- NA" and "x[x<x_low_outlier]<-NA"?

Comment: When you do `x<x_low_outlier` it compares value in column-wise fashion. So [1, 1] is compared with first value in x_low_outlier, then `[2, 1]` with second value in `x_low_outlier` and so on. What we actually want is to compare second value of `x_low_outlier` with `[1, 2]` instead. Hence, we transpose the data.

Comment: Thank you. But I tested these codes. "x[t(t(x) < x_low_outlier)] <- NA" produces the same results as "x[x < x_low_outlier)] <- NA". And "x[sweep(x, 2, x_low_outlier, `<`)] <- NA" seems the right code. So does the "x[] <- Map(function(z, q1, iqr) replace(z, z < (q1 - iqr), NA), x, x_q1, x_iqr)" by r2evans.

Comment: I don't think so. Check the output of `x[t(t(x) < x_low_outlier)]` and `x[x < x_low_outlier]`. Do you get the same numbers?

Comment: Yes, Ronak. I checked and got the same numbers. Look forward to your reply.

Comment: @ChengChang It doesn't happen for me. Can you create the matrix/data.frame with `set.seed` so that we both have same numbers in `x` and can verify the results?

Comment: OK. Thank you for the suggestion:) Here is my test code and the output:
set.seed(123)
x<-as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(200, mean = 10, sd = 2),nrow =10))
x_Q1<-sapply(x, quantile, 0.25, na.rm = TRUE)
x_IQR<-sapply(x,IQR, na.rm = TRUE)
x_low_outlier<-x_Q1-x_IQR
   x1<-x[t(t(x))<x_low_outlier]
   x2<-x[x<x_low_outlier]

The output is: 
 [1] 6.066766 6.626613 7.723726 7.753783 6.902494 5.381662 7.558565
 [8] 6.664116 6.764235 8.696100 8.076287 6.970665 7.076489 7.497457

Comment: @ChengChang Please check my answer and comment again above. You have a bracket at wrong place. Try this. `x1 <- x[t(t(x) < x_low_outlier)]` and `x2<-x[x<x_low_outlier] `. Do you still get same numbers in `x1` and `x2` ?

Comment: SORRY! I did place a bracket at the wrong place. Now I understand your code:) Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I tend to prefer `sapply` or `lapply` for work on frames, mostly because it doesn't convert the data to a matrix (when not necessary).

```r
set.seed(42)
x <- as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(100, mean = 10, sd = 2), nrow = 10))
head(x)
#          V1        V2        V3        V4        V5        V6        V7        V8        V9       V10
# 1 12.741917 12.609739  9.386723 10.910900 10.411997 10.643851  9.265531  7.913762 13.025414 12.784233
# 2  8.870604 14.573291  6.437383 11.409675  9.277885  8.432322 10.370461  9.819627 10.515843  9.047652
# 3 10.726257  7.222279  9.656165 12.070207 11.516326 13.151455 11.163647 11.247036 10.176880 11.300697
# 4 11.265725  9.442422 12.429349  8.782147  8.546590 11.285799 12.799474  8.092953  9.758207 12.782221
# 5 10.808537  9.733357 13.790387 11.009910  7.263438 10.179521  8.545416  8.914342  7.611342  7.778422
# 6  9.787751 11.271901  9.139062  6.565983 10.865636 10.553101 12.605085 11.161993 11.223994  8.278415
```

If you want to calculate the lower outlier cutoff in one action (instead of Q1 and IQR separately, then this will work):

```r
x_fltr <- sapply(x, function(z)  quantile(z, 0.25, na.rm = TRUE) - IQR(z, na.rm = TRUE))
x_fltr
#   V1.25%   V2.25%   V3.25%   V4.25%   V5.25%   V6.25%   V7.25%   V8.25%   V9.25%  V10.25% 
# 7.280440 3.273885 7.045359 5.677660 6.188558 9.233803 8.873416 5.150275 7.792175 4.501860 
x[] <- Map(function(z, fltr) replace(z, z < fltr, NA), x, x_fltr)
head(x)
#          V1        V2        V3        V4        V5       V6        V7        V8        V9       V10
# 1 12.741917 12.609739  9.386723 10.910900 10.411997 10.64385  9.265531  7.913762 13.025414 12.784233
# 2  8.870604 14.573291        NA 11.409675  9.277885       NA 10.370461  9.819627 10.515843  9.047652
# 3 10.726257  7.222279  9.656165 12.070207 11.516326 13.15146 11.163647 11.247036 10.176880 11.300697
# 4 11.265725  9.442422 12.429349  8.782147  8.546590 11.28580 12.799474  8.092953  9.758207 12.782221
# 5 10.808537  9.733357 13.790387 11.009910  7.263438 10.17952        NA  8.914342        NA  7.778422
# 6  9.787751 11.271901  9.139062  6.565983 10.865636 10.55310 12.605085 11.161993 11.223994  8.278415
```

If you want to keep them separate, we can extend `Map` to deal with that pretty easily:

```r
set.seed(42)
x <- as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(100, mean = 10, sd = 2), nrow = 10))
x_q1 <- sapply(x, quantile, probs = 0.25, na.rm = TRUE)
x_q1
#    V1.25%    V2.25%    V3.25%    V4.25%    V5.25%    V6.25%    V7.25%    V8.25%    V9.25%   V10.25% 
#  9.826654  7.774582  8.824773  8.331409  8.694220 10.179557 10.445770  8.126827  9.665417  7.903420 
x_iqr <- sapply(x, IQR, na.rm = TRUE)
x_iqr
#        V1        V2        V3        V4        V5        V6        V7        V8        V9       V10 
# 2.5462146 4.5006972 1.7794142 2.6537486 2.5056612 0.9457542 1.5723535 2.9765517 1.8732414 3.4015604 
x[] <- Map(function(z, q1, iqr) replace(z, z < (q1 - iqr), NA), x, x_q1, x_iqr)
head(x)
#          V1        V2        V3        V4        V5       V6        V7        V8        V9       V10
# 1 12.741917 12.609739  9.386723 10.910900 10.411997 10.64385  9.265531  7.913762 13.025414 12.784233
# 2  8.870604 14.573291        NA 11.409675  9.277885       NA 10.370461  9.819627 10.515843  9.047652
# 3 10.726257  7.222279  9.656165 12.070207 11.516326 13.15146 11.163647 11.247036 10.176880 11.300697
# 4 11.265725  9.442422 12.429349  8.782147  8.546590 11.28580 12.799474  8.092953  9.758207 12.782221
# 5 10.808537  9.733357 13.790387 11.009910  7.263438 10.17952        NA  8.914342        NA  7.778422
# 6  9.787751 11.271901  9.139062  6.565983 10.865636 10.55310 12.605085 11.161993 11.223994  8.278415
```